# How to fontawesome 5 solid and regular icons n pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome-5

I am trying to embed fontawesome 5 icons in my project. I need to add icons in pseudo elements (:before, :after). I could add regular icons but not solid icons. Both have same unicode value. This is my css so far,

```
label.star:before {
  content: '\f005';
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
}
```

Now it displays regular star icon. How can I make it solid icon?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use font-family "Font Awesome 5 Solid"

Comment: I have tried that, but it is not working. The icon won't load. I am using the free version of fontawesome

Comment: can you please post the js fiddle for us? Also try using font-family:Font Awesome\ 5 Free - For ref : https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet

Answer (score 15):

To make it solid icon, add `font-weight: 900;`

```
label.star:before {
    content: '\f005';
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but...

If you need to change the icon style from Solid to Regular, just update the font-family:

```
font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free Regular';
```